# Callback between EJBs / local EJB calls

Tags: interface, callback, ejb, local

Can you register EJB A as callback in an MDB B?

`B.register(Aref)`

in B: `A.callback()`

What would be Aref if the EJBs use local calls?
`SessionContext.getEJBLocalObject()`?

Comment: Better formulated, I'd like to dispatch from the MDB to other beans A. And I wanted to dynamically make B known to the EJB, so I could have a dispatching mechanism from MBD to to A.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is not really possible in the proposed way.

If `B` is a Message Driven Bean, then it's never possible to call a method on it. In the messaging paradigm, the type of the receiver of a message is unknown. You thus can't reference an instance of the MDB. Instead, you post messages to a queue or topic and if your MDB is configured to listen to that its `onMessage()` method will be invoked.

Secondly, in EJB you don't often pass references around like in your example code. What kind of EJB bean is A supposed to be? A stateless session bean, or a stateful session bean?

In case it's a stateless session bean, the instance might not matter and you can probably just inject it:

```
@MessageDriven
public class NSMessageDrivenBean implements MessageListener {

    @EJB
    private A yourABean;

    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        // process message and then call A

        yourABean.someMethod();        

    }
}
```

If the callback needs to be done to a type that is unknown in advance (depending on the message being send), then one mechanism for this is via a `JMS reply`.

In the message being send to the message driven bean, you then include code like this:

```
message.setJMSReplyTo(someDestination);
message.setJMSCorrelationID(someCorrelationID);
```

`someDestination` represents your callback, it's a destination to which something is listening, and this something can then invoke the call on the stateless session bean (in the context of the client).

E.g. something like:

```
connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE).createConsumer(someDestination).setMessageListener(
    new MessageListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
           yourABean.someMethod();
        }
}
```

In this case, someDestination can be a temporary destination.